# Infinite loop and CPU usage on single core and multicore

Tags: java, multithreading, core-data, cpu-usage

Interviewer has asked me this question and I want to understand concept ie how CPU usages varies :

1) If infinite loop is running in single-threaded design with single core machine

2) If infinite loop is running in single-threaded design with multi-core machine ( 4 core )

3) If infinite loop is running in multi-threaded design with single core machine

4)If infinite loop is running in multi-threaded design with multi-core machine (4 core )

5) What will happen when application is having more threads then hardware core. For ex : Application is creating 30 threads in 4 core machine. Will it increase the performance of application or decrease the performance ?

6)  What will happen when application is having less threads then hardware core. For ex : Application is creating 5 threads in 4 core machine. Will it increase the performance of application or decrease the performance ?

Requesting you to explain the concepts so that things are clear. I have lot of confusion.

Comment: This is down to the operating system and the thread management system used by the OS.

Comment: I'm not a downvoter. But if I would be asked by first this 4 questions on interview, I would run away from that team, as this questions are practically useless.

Comment: "It depends" is the right answer for all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as the comments state, the complete answer will depend on all sorts of things, including:

- the OS and its thread scheduler
- tuning parameters / resource limits
- whether the system is running on bare metal or under a hypervisor
- load on the system due to other things that the application
- various aspects of the application not mentioned ...

However, we can give some "first approximation" answers, if we make some simplifying assumptions.

> 1) If infinite loop is running in single-threaded design with single core machine.

Lets call this the base-line case; i.e. the speedups described below are *relative* to this case.

> 2) If infinite loop is running in single-threaded design with multi-core machine ( 4 core )

No speedup.  Even though there are multiple cores, the application cannot use them.  A thread runs on a single core at a time.

> 3) If infinite loop is running in multi-threaded design with single core machine.

No speedup.  While there are N threads, each thread will get on average 1/N of the available execution time on the single available core.  A core can run only one thread at a time.

> 4)If infinite loop is running in multi-threaded design with multi-core machine (4 core )

Speedup of up to four-fold.

> 5) What will happen when application is having more threads then hardware core. For ex : Application is creating 30 threads in 4 core machine. Will it increase the performance of application or decrease the performance ?

If the application is CPU bound, you will get no more than four-fold speedup.  See 2) and 3) above.

> 6) What will happen when application is having less threads then hardware core. For ex : Application is creating 5 threads in 4 core machine. Will it increase the performance of application or decrease the performance ?

Your example does not make sense.  5 threads is MORE THAN 4 cores.  If you meant 3 threads on 4 cores, then the maximum speedup is three-fold for a CPU bound application.

---

Here are the main simplifying assumptions that I have made for the above:

- System is idle apart from the application under test.
- Not using hypervisor.
- Sufficient physical memory
- Application is CPU bound (not network or disk I/O bound)
- Application is long running
- Application's use of memory isn't stressing the available memory bandwith
- Application threads are not contending for locks, etc
- Physical cores, not "HT" cores
- No relevant OS-imposed resource limits on the application